# ElasticSearch Edge NGram Preserve Numbers

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on creating an autocompletion API for residential addresses.

I would like to preserve the numbers, so I don't get the following problem:

Let's say the index contains a couple of documents:

```
{"fullAddressLine": "Kooimanweg 10 1442BZ Purmerend", "streetName": "Kooimanweg", houseNumber: "10", "postCode": "1442BZ", "cityName": "Purmerend"}
{"fullAddressLine": "Kooimanweg 1009 1442BZ Purmerend", "streetName": "Kooimanweg", houseNumber: "1009", "postCode": "1442BZ", "cityName": "Purmerend"}
{"fullAddressLine": "Kooimanweg 1011 1442BZ Purmerend", "streetName": "Kooimanweg", houseNumber: "1011", "postCode": "1442BZ", "cityName": "Purmerend"}
{"fullAddressLine": "Kooimanweg 1013 1442BZ Purmerend", "streetName": "Kooimanweg", houseNumber: "1013", "postCode": "1442BZ", "cityName": "Purmerend"}
```

These are the settings and mappings:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "EdgeNGramFilter": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 40
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "EdgeNGramAnalyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "EdgeNGramFilter"
                    ]
                },
                "keywordAnalyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "asciifolding",
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "fullAddressLine": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "EdgeNGramAnalyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "standard",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "keywordAnalyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this would be the ElasticSearch query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "fullAddressLine": {
                        "query": "kooiman 10",
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this is:

```
Kooimanweg 10 1442BZ Purmerend
Kooimanweg 1009 1442BZ Purmerend
Kooimanweg 1011 1442BZ Purmerend
Kooimanweg 1033 1442BZ Purmerend
```

This works, but I would only like to see this:

```
Kooimanweg 10 1442BZ Purmerend
```

**How can I change the query or mappings/settings to achieve this result?**

When using the "EdgeNgramAnalyzer" analyzer on "Test 1009" I get:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "t",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "te",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "tes",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "test",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "1",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "10",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "100",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "1009",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**I want to reserve numbers so they don't get split.**

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: Are you OK to use other than edge ngram? Or you want ngram behaviour only on alpha/alpha numeric words but not only on numeric words?

Comment: Hi @Gibbs, I would like to stick with edge ngram because I need this type of automcompletion. I have experience with the Completion Suggester for example, but that doesn't fit my needs in this case.

I want the edge ngram tokenizer to *not* make ngrams out of numeric words (like "10") but it should make ngram out of "1442BZ".